# EF Core 3rd party library migration not running

Tags: c#, .net, entity-framework, .net-core, entity-framework-core

I have created a 3rd party library that has a db table. The purpose of this library is to be used across several other projects I have. It provides infrastructure work (specific user permissions). So in order not to write the same code in each service I have refactored it into a library. This libpublic class

```
public class UserAccessContext : DbContext
{
    public UserAccessContext(DbContextOptions options)
        : base(options)
    {
        Database.Migrate();
    }

    public DbSet<ClientPermission> ClientPermission{ get; set; }

    protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder modelBuilder)
    {
        base.OnModelCreating(modelBuilder);

        modelBuilder.Entity<ClientPermission>().HasKey(c => new { c.UserId, c.PermissionId});
    }
}
```

I have created migration scripts (Add-Migration...) and the script seems ok. It creates the ClientPermission table. Imported the library to one of the services (Service A) and I can see that the migration script of UserAccess library does not run when I start Service A. The only migration script that runs is the one that belongs to ServiceA. When `UserAccessContext` is called `Database.Migrate()` is executed but it does not find any changes that need to be applied.
Why does this happen and how can I enforce it to run `UserAccessContext` migration script?

Comment: check migration table located in the database

Comment: Make sure the right MigrationsAssembly is used in your DbContextOptions. By default, the current assembly is used but you need to use the assembly where the migration code is (your library here if I understand you well). Check this link : https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/managing-schemas/migrations/projects?tabs=dotnet-core-cli

Comment: @CemSOYDING Maybe my initial post was not clear. This is a 3rd party lib. I have currently ServiceADbContext and UserAccessContext . Each context has its own migration script created. UserAccessContext belongs to LibraryUserAccess and has its own migration script created. This script is not executed along with the ServiceADbContext migration script.

Comment: Yep, then you're right it should work. I just tested with the following setup : A class library with the model, the DbContext and the migration code, a console app that references the lib and makes use of the DbContext. I can see the migrations applied. Maybe something related to the database provider you're using ? (I did my tests with SQLite)

Comment: Yes you are right. It works. I specify the 3rd part library dll as migration assembly for the UserAccessContext options. Thanks

Comment: Alright then I'm posting the same message as an answer to your question so that it helps other people looking for this solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make sure the right MigrationsAssembly is used in your DbContextOptions. By default, the current assembly is used but you need to use the assembly where the migration code is (your library here if I understand you well). Check this link :
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/managing-schemas/migrations/projects?tabs=dotnet-core-cli